# QR code reader to scan multiple qr codes in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, qr-code, zbar-sdk

I would like to integrate a qr code scanner in my iOS application that can scan more than two qr codes from a picture.Is there any good scanner available?I have tried ZBarSDK in iOS, but it scans only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When you scan with ZBarSDK it gives you scanned result of all BarCodes. But we pick only one. You can check values of this for loop.

```
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
        [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
        ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;


        for(symbol in results){
            // EXAMPLE: Usually we just grab the first barcode
NSLog(@"REaded Text %@",symbol.data);
// Check out values here, it should return multiple results.
            break;
}
```

Comment: Else you can use this BarCode Reader.
http://redlaser.com/developers/documentation/ios/using-the-sdk/